# Problem with injective and surjective functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

prove that
$$\forall f:X \to Y \ \exists Z$$
$$\mbox{, injective function -}$$
$$h : X \to Z  $$
$$\mbox{and surjective function -}$$
$$g: Z \to Y$$
$$\mbox{so that}$$ $$f = gh$$

How should I approach proving this?

Comment: Please do not repost your questions. Even less so with identical wording!

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ Try $Z = X \times Y$.

Answer (score 0):

In case $f$ is injective (in particular, when $X$ is empty), there's an obvious choice for $Z$, $g$ and $h$.

If $f$ is not injective, then we have for some $x,x'\in X$, that $f(x)=f(x')$. To make it injective, we thus should somehow keep track of $x$ in $f(x)$.

For example, by considering $(x,f(x))$. Now choose $Z$ a sufficiently large set that:

1. contains all pairs $(x,f(x))$;
2. admits a surjection onto $Y$.

> **Hint:** The projections from a product $\pi_A: A\times B \to A$ and $\pi_B: A\times B \to B$ are surjections.